# How to convert String to List object in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying Spring MVC example. I have a testBean which has List type variable like

```
  private List<HashMap<String, String>> books;
```

In my controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/booksList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String displayBooks(@ModelAttribute TestBean testBean, Model model, HttpSession   session) {
     // some code here
}
```

In my jsp page I have

```
<form:form action="booksList.html" method="post" modelAttribute="testBean">
        <form:hidden path="books" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form:form>
```

When I submit this form I am getting this error

> Cannot convert value of type [`java.lang.String`] to required type [`java.util.HashMap`] for property '`books[0]`'.

How can I solve this error ? please help

**Updated:**

[I have seen that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637324/save-many-to-many-in-spring-mvc) I can do this way also.

```
 @InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {              
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "testBean", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class) {                
        @Override           
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
            TestBean testBean = new TestBean();                
            if (element != null) {
                List<HashMap<String, String>> id = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) element;
                testBean.setFilters(id);
            }
            return testBean;
        }
        });       
   }
```

But I don't understand the above method fully there may be some mistakes in what I have written. And I don't know how and from where I can call `convertElement(Object element)` method. i do understand `initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)` will call jsut before my controller method `public String displayBooks(...)`. Even I don't know if its the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it above, you're trying to represent an extremely complex type (a `List` of `Map`s) with a single text field. Your first step should be working out how you want to display that information in a web form. Then try using "canned data" (e.g. a `TestBean` that you've loaded up with fake `books`) and see if your form looks how you expect it to.

You might find it easier if you change the way your `books` collection is stored. Having such a complex type as part of a "bean" while *allowed*, is probably not *recommended*. Consider using a `List<BookBean>` where a `BookBean` holds a collection of `BookDetailBean`, and a `BookDetailBean` holds that String-to-String relationship that you previously had in your `Map`.